# Difference between phrases that mean 'copy'

Tags: phrase-usage

Could you tell me the difference between: " follow one's lead", "do an impression of" and "follow in one's footsteps"? Thank you so much for your helpfulness

Answer (score 3):

**Follow one's lead** is to perform something **exactly** as being shown.  One can be told: "Follow my lead and do exactly as I do" when being instructed in fighting fires.

**Do an impression of** is to do an action or a voice which is similar enough to the original, so it can be identified as the original.  People do impressions of famous people, which are not exact, but the impression is identifiable

**Follow in one's footsteps** is to perform a series of actions similar to the original, usually concerning foundation actions or learning.  For example, he **followed in his parents' foot steps** by going to college.

Comment: Thank you so much. Hope you have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

To **do an impression of** someone (usually a famous person) is to imitate their voice and mannerisms in a humorous way as an entertainment. The context is quite different from the other two expressions, which refer to copying the actions of someone you know for a practical purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful answer!